# Change td bg color based on php echo value

Tags: php, html, css

I have table rows having % change value printed using php echo in td element. I want to change background color based on php echo value. i.e if value >= 20 % -> Red, value 0-19% -> Yellow and value <= 0% -> Green.

**Code which colors td element if contains value (without %):**

```
<td <?php if($array_select[array_keys($array_select)[0]] >= 2): ?> 
style="background-color:#F78181; text-align: center;" 
<?php endif; ?> 
style=" background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
border-color: #999999;"><?php echo $array_select[array_keys($array_select)[0]];?></td>
```

**Not working here:**

```
<td style=" background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
<?php if($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 20): ?> 
style="background-color:#F78181; text-align: center;" 
<?php endif; ?> 
border-color: #999999;"><?php echo "${change[array_keys($change)[0]]}%";?></td>
```

**Updated code with answer that gives error:**

```
$value2 = $change[array_keys($change)[2]];
if($value2 >= 20){
    $Style2 = 'style="background-color:#FF0000; text-align:center;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px; text-align: center;border-style: solid; border-color: #999999"';
}elseif($value2 > 0 && $value2 < 20){
    $Style2 = 'style="background-color:#FFFF00; text-align:center;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px; text-align: center;border-style: solid; border-color: #999999"';
}elseif($value2 <= 0){
    $Style2 = 'style="background-color:#009933; text-align:center;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px; text-align: center;border-style: solid; border-color: #999999"';
}
```

And

```
<td <?php echo $style2;?>><?php echo $change[array_keys($change)[2]];?>%</td>
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Error in php code `if(change[array_keys($change)[0]] `

Comment: Edited above code, added missing $, still does not work.

Comment: why do you use `:` and `endif;`?

Comment: if `$change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 20` does not return `true`, the `style`-tag will never be opened and when it does you close it before you get to `border-color`

Comment: @SamApostel- That's a "convention" in "templates" that use PHP.  Not my favorite syntax, but perfectly legit: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It has -50% value and I chnaged code to `<?php if($change[array_keys($change)[0]] <= 20): ?>` still doesn't work. Suggest me if there is other better solution.

Comment: So, this is almost impossible to help with because we have no idea what your `$change` and `$array_select` arrays contain, so we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: You apply the attribute 'style' two times when the condition is met.

Comment: @cale_b thx for link, I just thought it might be easier to read for most people with standard {}

Comment: What would be FAR better is to set the styles in a variable *outside* of the HTML, then simply echo the `$style` into the HTML, rather than the logic mixed in with the HTML, which gets messy.

Comment: Got above code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211245/change-colour-of-table-td-based-on-value)

Comment: you *got the idea* from there.  That example is *far simpler*, and not nearly as difficult to follow.  **Please note the earlier comment** about this being impossible without knowing your variables `$change` and `$array_select`

Comment: Yes, but I am just returning array values which will range from around -200 to 400 %. In above case it is -50%

Comment: Please include more of your code to show the loop that you are working with.  Please also include the input data that your are using.  Show us `$change` and `$array_select` and whatever else is essential. Sunil's answer is not DRY, should have an `else`, and inline styling is a messy look as is bouncing in and out of php tags.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad There is a different between `$Style2` and `$style2`.  Please fix this typo (choose just one case-sensitive variable name) and include in your update: the values of `$change` and `$array_select` so that we can provide you with a DRY and thoughtful way to code your project.  The current answers are not using best practices.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad How can i simply display php echo values,, my code :  <?php echo $_product->getData('ayyappa_coupon_code_offer');?>       and screen shot : https://imgur.com/lCaMUG3 i need to add bgcolor for Use this code get 10 % discount.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$value = $array_select[array_keys($array_select)[0]];
if($value >= 20){
    $style = 'style="background-color:#FF0000; text-align: center;border-color: #999999"';
}elseif($value > 0 && $value < 20){
    $style = 'style="background-color:#FFFF00; text-align: center;border-color: #999999"';
}elseif($value <= 0){
    $style = 'style="background-color:#009933; text-align: center;border-color: #999999"';
}
?>
<td <?php echo $style;?>><?php echo $array_select[array_keys($array_select)[0]];?>%</td>
```

First save your value in variable and check/compare value before apply in  , And also create style code in php variable according to condition. Now apply these two variables in final html code.

Comment: Nice explanation, but it's difficult for me to apply to all `td` elements. As above code was just for the first value in array. I added same code again and changed to `$value2 = $array_select[array_keys($array_select)[1]];` , `$value2`, `$style2` and  `<?php echo $style2;?>` for second value but it's showing error: `Notice: Undefined variable: style2` I will have to repeat above code with changes 3 times more for rest 3 elements. Also there is second array having 4 values which needs highlighting. Can we do highlighting using 2 time code repetition for 2 arrays elsewill need to repeat 8 time.

Comment: Please add full code with array values $array_select, and add above code inside foreach of $array_select. But for more please post full code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

from the info you gave us, I think this should work:

```
<td style=" background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
  <?php if($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 20): ?> 
    background-color:#F78181; text-align: center; 
  <?php endif; ?> 
  border-color: #999999;">
      <?php echo "${change[array_keys($change)[0]]}%";?>
</td>
```

Comment: I can't test it now, will test tomorrow, it would be great if other 2 conditions are also added to above code as in future values can change.